# Issue in opening a file type after unzipping

Tags: file-format, encryption, decryption

I downloaded a file from this link https://storage.cloud.google.com/gresearch/smallcnnzoo-dataset/cifar10.tar.xz, and I successfully downloaded the archive file.I unzipped it using 7-Zip. After unzipping the file format type is file[image: FileFormat].

I converted it to CSV extension but I am unable to read the data its encoded like below
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's obviously not CSV, what made you think it is? You should contact provider of the dataset or use the program that was supplied with it to read it.